# number of euler cycle graphs with degree of 2

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, eulerian-path

I got the following question -

> what is the number of 2-regular graphs containing an Euler cycle with n vertices

what I came up with so far -

as I understand we are looking for a circle (every vertex is of degree of 2)

so let's say we pick some random vertex - we have to pick his neighbors 
out of $n-1$ vertices - $$\left(\begin{array}{c}n-1\\ 2\end{array}\right)$$

and then we have to fill all the other vertices untill we reach the end of the cicrcle - $$(n-3)!$$
so the final answer would be $$\left(\begin{array}{c}n-1\\ 2\end{array}\right)\cdot (n-3)!$$

It works for $n=3$ and $n=4$ and I think it works for $n=5$

what do you think? what is wrong with my logic here?
how I solve this kind of problems?

Comment: How does your formula work for $n=4$? There is only one possible 2-regular graph with $4$ vertices.

Comment: as I understand there is 3 such graphs ... can you explain how did you count?

Comment: With four vertices the only possible 2-regular graph is the "square", isn't it? What are the other two graphs?

Comment: let's say we have numbers in a square from 1 to 4 (clockwise): {1,2,3,4},{1,3,2,4},{1,2,4,3}

Comment: But they represent the same graph.

Comment: for the first graph for example 1 knows 2 and 4 but in the second 1 doesn't know 2 so the graphs are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [2-regular graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Two-RegularGraph.html) which has an [Euler cycle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerianCycle.html) with $n$ vertices is necessarily connected and therefore it is a cycle-graph with $n$ vertices. If we are counting the labeled graphs then the number should be for $n>2$
$$\frac{n!\;\mbox{(permutations)}}{2\cdot n\; \mbox{(orientations)(rotations)}}=\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$$
See  [OEIS's A001710](https://oeis.org/A001710).

Comment: @misha312 Do I understand your question correctly? Is it just like the number of necklaces one can make with $n$ distinct beads?

Comment: yes that's exactly it thanks